# Pattern matching Haskell lists

Tags: haskell, types

I'm starting to learn Haskell using [the University of Pennsylvania's free online course materials](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html). These have been put online deliberately so I presume I'm not helping anyone's homework by asking this question.

I get a number of compiler errors from the following function, which I'm using to answer part of the first assignment, and I can't figure out why. My function is:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther [x] = [x]
doubleEveryOther [x:y] = [x:(y*2)]
doubleEveryOther [x:y:ys] = [x:y*2:doubleEveryOther ys]
```

The errors I get are:

```
01.hs:18:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    In the pattern: x : y
    In the pattern: [x : y]
    In an equation for ‘doubleEveryOther’:
        doubleEveryOther [x : y] = [x : (y * 2)]

01.hs:18:27:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    Relevant bindings include
      y :: [a0] (bound at 01.hs:18:21)
      x :: a0 (bound at 01.hs:18:19)
    In the expression: x : (y * 2)
    In the expression: [x : (y * 2)]
    In an equation for ‘doubleEveryOther’:
        doubleEveryOther [x : y] = [x : (y * 2)]

01.hs:19:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    In the pattern: x : y : ys
    In the pattern: [x : y : ys]
    In an equation for ‘doubleEveryOther’:
        doubleEveryOther [x : y : ys] = [x : y * 2 : doubleEveryOther ys]

01.hs:19:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    In the expression: x : y * 2 : doubleEveryOther ys
    In the expression: [x : y * 2 : doubleEveryOther ys]
    In an equation for ‘doubleEveryOther’:
        doubleEveryOther [x : y : ys] = [x : y * 2 : doubleEveryOther ys]
```

Can anyone help me understand why my patterns are not matching the right types?

Comment: Too tired for a full answer, sorry, but the following might give you an idea: `[x,y]`, `(x:y:ys)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple: `[]` denotes a list of elements. And `:` denotes joining an element and a list. So `[x:ys]` means actually `[[x,y1,y2..]]` - note double brackets. So it's a list of lists of `Integer` in your case and not a list of `Integer`.

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther [x]= [x]
doubleEveryOther [x,y] = [x, y*2]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:ys) = x : y*2 : doubleEveryOther ys
```

If you want all 4 equations to use the same syntax, then you can't use `[]` as it doesn't allow `ys`, so you have to use `:` everywhere:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther (x:[])= x:[]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:[]) = x : y*2 : []
doubleEveryOther (x:y:ys) = x : y*2 : doubleEveryOther ys
```

Comment: *`[x:ys]` means actually `[[x,y1,y2..]]`*. That's not 100% accurate. In the pattern `[x:ys]`, `ys` can be nil, in which case there is no `y1` and `y2`.

Answer (score 2):

The code should be:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther [x] = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:[]) = [x, (y*2)]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:ys) = x: y*2 : doubleEveryOther ys
```

You can't pattern match on a list directly, because the list syntax is just syntax sugar. You have to match on function calls (specifically calls to `(:)`, the cons operator). And those matches need to be enclosed in parentheses.

And you don't enclose cons calls in brackets. `[1 : 2 : []]` is the same as `[[1, 2]]`. Just to make it a bit clearer, in your code you have `[x : y*2]`. `x` and `y` are both `Int`s. But cons `(:)` is of type `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. You're calling it with two `Int`s, not an `Int` and a `[Int]` like you should.

Comment: `[x]` is a valid pattern for a singleton list, though; it doesn't have to be `(x:[])`. Garry got that right.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. Can you elaborate on why your final pattern match works, but using the cons operator in the penultimate match doesn't? I want to make sure I really understand this.

Comment: Do you mean on the right hand side of the equation? `x: (y*2): doubles ys` works because it takes the result of `doubles`, conses `y` to the front, and then conses `x` to the front of that. The right of line 4 could be expressed as `x: (y*2): []` to express the cons's directly. It takes an empty list, conses on `y`, then conses on `x`. But because we already know the entire list, we can use the list syntax sugar to write it directly `[x, y*2]`. We can't use list syntax sugar on the last line because we don't know the result of `doubleEveryOther`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, your 3rd line is a part of 4th line, so

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther [x]= [x]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:ys) = x : y*2 : doubleEveryOther ys
```